# using TextTransform.exe to generate code from edmx file

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, command-line, t4, edmx

I have an edmx file that I generated using edmgen2, I am using the POCO Entity Generator.tt file that Visual Studio uses or generates when I click "Add Code Generation Item" in the edmx designer.

I want to generate the cs (C#) files that Visual Studio generates (including views and stored procedures), but in command line using the TextTransform.exe.

First, is this even possible with only the edmx and tt file? if not, what's the right way to do what I'm trying to do.

If it is possible, then what's the correct syntax?

Thanks a Bunch!

Comment: I don't know about edmx, but generally the syntax is: `TextTransform.exe -out file.cs file.tt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have an EDMX containing the model and .TT file that generates the C# artifact.

So I made a simple experiment where I took a simple EDMX file and the OOB .TT file and ran TextTransform.exe on the .TT file. It worked fine except I had to copy the [EF include file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477603.aspx) into the same folder as the .TT file.

The .TT file uses the host to resolve paths but TextTransform.exe supports this submethod of host methods as well.

For me once I found the TextTransform.exe and the [EF include file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477603.aspx) it was as easy as this to generate the C# artifact:

```
TextTransform.exe Model1.tt
```